# Which (Intel?) graphics chipset are integrated in barebone AsRock BeeBox machines?

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics, 4k-resolution, htpc, barebone

I spent hours to find out googling which Intel? graphics chipset are in BeeBox machines, with no success, especially in [AsRock BeeBox J4205](https://www.asrock.com/nettop/Intel/Beebox%20Series%20(Apollo%20Lake)/index.asp) Neither the [official site](https://www.asrock.com/nettop/Intel/Beebox%20Series%20(Apollo%20Lake)/index.asp) neither Amazon or other shops do not even mention the graphics chipset in the specification.

The only thing I can see that one of the two HDMI output supports 4K/60Hz.

(I would like to have a home theater PC with Windowzer and KODI and smooth I mean smooooth playback, not using 4K just simple Full HD is enough)

Missing I something? Why the graphics chipset do not even mentioned in the spec when the product is probably positioned as an entry level HTPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find the graphics chipset because there isn't one. The graphics processor is integrated into the central processor and what you have depends 100% on the CPU. You can find out what the CPU has from the Intel product specification pages.

They don't tell you the chipset explicitly because it is *implicit* in the CPU choice.

According to your page you either have

1. [Intel® Pentium® Processor J4205](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95591/intel-pentium-processor-j4205-2m-cache-up-to-2-6-ghz.html)

   - Intel® HD Graphics 505
2. [Intel® Celeron® Processor J3455](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95594/intel-celeron-processor-j3455-2m-cache-up-to-2-3-ghz.html)

   - Intel® HD Graphics 500

Comment: Many thanks. Is makes sense, and I did know I was missing something fundamental. As I see those are supporting H.265. However I can not found video playback oriented benchmark comparisons, just gaming oriented, where this chipset performs poor (relative). Is there any benchmark source where I can see its pure video playback full hd 1080 performance?

Comment: The video acceleration side tends to be a dedicated hardware block with fixed performance across the range. You might be able to find something specific at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Capabilities_(GPU_video_acceleration)

Comment: Thanks this is very useful